# How do I get "Enum.CONSTANT" to return some type (e.g. Color)?

Tags: java, enums

I want the field constants of my enum to return instances of the `Color` class instead of some constant values, is this possible in Java? I would like to avoid having to retrieve them through an accessor method. For example, this is the way I want to be able to use my enum:

```
Color color;
color = ExtendedColor.RED;
color = ExtendedColor.FOO;
color = ExtendedColor.BAZ;
```

---

```
import java.awt.*;

/**
 * Static utility enum for providing a much greater variety of Colors to choose from, some of which are not
 * included as constants in the Color class
 */
public enum ExtendedColor {
    RED(Color.RED),
    ORANGE(Color.ORANGE),
    YELLOW(Color.YELLOW),
    FOO(10, 20, 30),
    BAR(90, 90, 90),
    BAZ(30, 30, 30);

    private Color color;

    private ExtendedColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    private ExtendedColor(int r, int g, int b) {
        this.color = new Color(r, g, b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use an `enum` then? Just declare a static class with color constants in it.

Comment: "I would like to avoid having to retrieve them through an accessor method" you can always make the `Color` inside your `enum` `public final`

Answer (score 2):

You can create a class with public static fields instead and access the fields directly `ExtendedColor.COLOR1`.

```
import java.awt.*;

public class ExtendedColor {
    public static final Color COLOR1 = ...;
    public static final Color COLOR2 = ...;
    ...
}
```

Comment: I don't see why this answer deserved a downvote so +1

Answer (score 2):

One approach is given in the first answer. Another approach is to define a `colorValue` method in the `ExtendedColor` enum which returns the actual Color.

```
public enum ExtendedColor {
  ...
  public Color colorValue() {
    return color;
  }
}
```

And then you will have

```
Color color;
color = ExtendedColor.RED.colorValue();
color = ExtendedColor.FOO.colorValue();
color = ExtendedColor.BAZ.colorValue();
```